# cgrulesengd-like support for cgroup v2

Tags: linux, cgroup

I was wondering if there are any best practices for automatically assigning processes to certain v2 cgroups based on a rules file or something similar. Pretty much what cgrulesengd did for v1. I have tried to find something similar but not much pops up.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is now available there as of May 06 2021, but you have to build from source.

Get it from the release here:

```
https://github.com/libcgroup/libcgroup/releases/tag/v2.0
```

And run

```
./configure
make
```